# JValidate and $.ajax together

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm just learning Jquery, but I'm going crazy trying to add a validation client/server side.
I use Jvalidate and it just work when i check it "alone", without the "$.ajax" part,
but when I put it all together Firebug launch an error :

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id
>     $('#inputSKU').submit(function(){

...and I don't why...

My objective is that once validation is right (client/remote) use the url from the $ajax 
to inset into the database...

Could you take a look to my code, please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>

<!-- http://localhost/260814/index.html -->

<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="additional-methods.js"></script>   
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('document').ready(function() {//documentready



    jQuery.validator.addMethod("SKUCorrecto",function(value,element,param)

    {//validatoraddmethod       
        if(this.optional(element))
            {//This is not a 'required' element and the input is empty
            return true;
            }
        if(/^[0-9]{11}$/.test(value))
            {
            return true;
            }
        return false;
    },"Please enter a valid SKU");//addmethodend


     $("#inputSKU").validate({ //validate

     onkeyup: false,
     rules: {
         SKU: { required: true, SKUCorrecto:true, remote:"check_SKU.php" },
     },
    messages: {
        SKU:{ remote: "sku ok info de remote" }
    },  

    $('#inputSKU').submit(function(){   
        $('#PaginaResultado').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");      
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'post_receiver.php',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){            
            $('#PaginaResultado').html(data);
            $('#inputSKU')[0].reset();            
        })
        .fail(function() {           
            //alert( "" );            
        });     
        return false;
    });

});//validate

 });//documentready
</script>


<form id="inputSKU" method="POST">
  <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="sku">SKU: *</label></td>
            <td><input id="sku" name="SKU" type="text" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>  
          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" /></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>

<div id="PaginaResultado"> paginaresultado </div> 

</html>
```

With this code ***validation doesn't work*** and I can't solve the Firebug error...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: according to the docs, it looks like `$('#inputSKU').submit(function(){..} ` should be something like `submitHandler: function() {..}`

Comment: Thank you so much. I will never find it by myself. JValidate requires that handler. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've put your submit event binder/handler inside the validate object-

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() { //document ready - don't actually need to quote this, document is a JavaScript object

       jQuery.validator.addMethod("SKUCorrecto", function (value, element, param) { //validatoraddmethod       
            if (this.optional(element)) { // This is not a 'required' element and the input is empty
                return true;
            }

            if (/^[0-9]{11}$/.test(value)) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }, 
        "Please enter a valid SKU"); // add method end


        $("#inputSKU").validate({ // validate
            onkeyup: false,
            rules: {
                SKU: { required: true, SKUCorrecto:true, remote:"check_SKU.php" },
            },
            messages: {
                SKU: { remote: "sku ok info de remote" }
            } // removed invalid trailing comma  
         }); // end of validate

        $('#inputSKU').submit(function(){   
            $('#PaginaResultado').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");      
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'post_receiver.php',
                data: $(this).serialize()
            })
            .done(function(data){            
                $('#PaginaResultado').html(data);
                $('#inputSKU')[0].reset();            
            })
            .fail(function() {           
                //alert( "" );            
            });     
            return false;
        });
    });// document ready
</script>
```

Whilst it is perfectly valid to have a function within an object, it needs to still be in the key/value format as per-

```
var foo = { 
    functionKey: function () {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The error message you saw was that there was no key.

In your case, looking at the code, I don't think you meant to put the event handler inside the object anyway, so I have moved it out. Maintaining good formatting, and- in particular - strong indentation on source code is extremely helpful in guiding you to structure your code correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help and answer. I can solve the problem helped by Ronnie. All must be inside validate but I didn't know that submithandler was obligatory. Lot of thx!!